# Swift: Custom Slider (Slide To Unlock style)

Tags: swift, xcode, slider, uislider

I am trying to implement a slider in the known slide to unlock style from older iphones to perform an action inside my swift app. The Slider should change background color and change the text inside while dragging. When the user drags til the end, the thumbView should stick to the right side and wait for a confirmation (some event) coming in to finally present a new view.

The slider should look something like this:

[image: State One] First state

[image: State two] Second state while dragging

[image: State three] Third state after releasing

I have found a few things on the internet but nothing that comes close to what I want to do. How would I go about doing this? My guess would be a combination of views with drag events but I feel like there must be an easier way. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a UISlider with a transparent track on a rectangle view with your text and color. You can set your image as the UISlider's thumb and receive events as the value changes and when the user touches and releases it.

You can use that to for example, animate the thumb back to the start when the user releases on any place except the end of the track. Also, you can set the slider's value from 0 to 1 and use it to calculate the color, so it changes smoothly.

When the user releases on the end of the track, you activate the activity indicator and start your process to present the next view....

Even though this is a possibility, I think I'd try doing a custom control using a pan gesture. It'd give you more control and you could for example choose how the thumb image animates when going back to the start on release.... I dont' think you can do that with UISlider's setValue(animated:).